# How to handle the return type of a method that sometimes return a case class object and sometimes returns a Future of that case class

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, future

Let's say I have 4 Objects that share the same method called `getParentName()`.

two of the object `getParentName()` returns `Info`, which is just a case class

```
object Jack extends Person {
   override def getParentName(): Info = {...}
}

object Mila extends Person {
   override def getParentName(): Info = {...}
}
```

and the other two returns a Future[Info] :

```
object Mike @Inject() (wsclient: WSClient) extends Person {
   override def getParentName(): Future[Info] = {...}
}

object Amy @Inject() (wsclient: WSClient) extends Person {
   override def getParentName(): Future[Info] = {...}
}
```

and now I want to have `PeopleManager` class that is iterating on those objects list and getting `getParentName()` results:

```
class PeopleManager {

    def getParentsNames ():??? = {
       listOfPeople.map(person => person.getParentName)
    }

}
```

but im not sure what is the right way to handle `getParentsNames()` return type...

the controller will use `PeopleManager` in an Action the to release a `GET` method for getting parents names. what will be a good way to handle this situation?

thanks!

Comment: Could you just make everything return a Future, some of which are just wrappers that complete immediately?

Comment: Then what is the return type of `getParentName` in class or trait `Person`?

Comment: @JoeK some other method are just basic calculations and some I need to perform api calls inside to calculate the return type so I get back a future. I could maybe wrap the ones that are with no future in a future but it seems weird...like a bad practice

Comment: My thought is that the `getParentName` in `Person` should have the most general return type. Usually that means a common superclass or trait, but in this case I am thinking of it as general in time. `Future[Info]` represents an `Info` that is available now or will be available in the future. `Info` represents an `Info` that is available now, so it is "more specific".

The other option is `Either[Info, Future[Info]]` which seems equally ugly.

Comment: Show the definition of `Person`. I suspect, you'll answer your own question while trying to come up with it. Hint: you want to return `Future` everywhere.

Comment: @JoeK why is `Either` ugly? Because it suggests an error on the left side? Possible. However I still think such a type is the way to go. Potentially something home-made: `sealed trait Computation` `case class Sync(res: Info) extends Computation` `case class Delayed(res: Future[Info]) extends Computation`

Comment: I'd also go with always returning `Future`. The one reason not to is if you want to handle "immediate" values differently, but this doesn't seem like it would happen here.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov I feel that this is the way I want to go too, but how would I go about that? something like `def getParentName() = Future { if (name == "Johan") Info("Johan Dad", "Johan Mom") } ` ? dont mind the stupid example I gave im just trying to emphasise that some of the `getParentName` methods will naturally return a Future since they performing http calls, and some ave simple calculations..

Comment: @Joe `Future.successful` is better than `Future.apply` here (and generally if you already have the value or calculation is trivial and can't fail): `if (name == "Johan") Future.successful(Info("Johan Dad", "Johan Mom")) else <something that returns Future>`